# Getting value of next node using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

What is the quickest way to obtain the next node of a line using jQuery? Here is the generated markup of a `TreeList` which is a type of `GridView` asp.net. I have to have to obtain the `lblWorkItemId` which is `199`. Please consider that this is from a bound control.

```
<tr id="ctl00_PageContent_rtlRshItems_ctl04__2" class="rtlR rtlRL" style="background-color:Lavender;">

<td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:90px;">
    <div id="ctl00_PageContent_rtlRshItems_ctl04_rcbStatut" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Windows7">
        <table class="rcbFocused" style="border-width: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse;" summary="combobox">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="rcbReadOnly">
                    <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
                        <input id="ctl00_PageContent_rtlRshItems_ctl04_rcbStatut_Input" class="rcbInput" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Submitted" name="ctl00$PageContent$rtlRshItems$ctl04$rcbStatut" autocomplete="off">
                    </td>
                    <td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight">
                        <a id="ctl00_PageContent_rtlRshItems_ctl04_rcbStatut_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input id="ctl00_PageContent_rtlRshItems_ctl04_rcbStatut_ClientState" type="hidden" name="ctl00_PageContent_rtlRshItems_ctl04_rcbStatut_ClientState" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</td>

<td class=" rtlCL" style="width:0px;">
    <asp:label id="lblWorkItemId" text="199" visible="false"> </asp:label>
</td>
```

The following javascript method will be called when the selected value of the combobox will be changed to a certain value:

```
    function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        if (item.get_text() == "Refused") {
            var treeList = $find("<%= rtlRshItems.ClientID %>");
            // var workItemId = [...]
            OpenReasonWindow(workItemId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at .next()?
http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: Elaborating on Adam's Comment... `$(this).next('#lblWorkItemID').text();` will iterate the DOM to the next element with an ID of lblWorkItemID and grab the text of it, $(this) refers to the element that you changed in your function, looks like a select list controller. Should be what you need.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy not if that's not a direct sibling. Given the markup and assuming the event is fired on the input, it would be best to go up to the containing row and use find on the matching id.  Note that the id will likely be munged by ASP.NET since it's inside a control.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, this returning an empty string...

Comment: There is some inconsistence in your markup. The first `td` looks like copypaste from browser source, but in the next one contains an `asp:label` element. Do you mix client source and aspx markup? If so, take into account that when you set web control `Visible` property to `false` it  not rendered on a page. Maybe it's would be better to use `asp:HiddenField` control instead of Label if you don't need to show it.

Comment: It's an exact copy-paste taken from firebug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code template:

```
    function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
        var item = eventArgs.get_item();
        if (item.get_text() == "Rejetée") {
            var combo = $('input[id*="rcbStatut_Input"]')
            var workItemId = combo.closest('tr.rtlRL').find('[id$="lblWorkItemId"]').attr('text');
            OpenReasonWindow(workItemId);
        }
    }
```

Note: I would typically apply this sort of handler unobtrusively, not in mark up.

Comment: actually `treeList` is for the entire grid... How can I get the current row?

Comment: @JFB - What's `item`, then?  Is it the input that is changed?  See my update under that assumption.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. `item` is the RadComboBox item that has been selected from the drop down list.

Comment: @JFB - from the markup, it looks like that will be the input element.  Give what I have now a try and see if it doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look here for more info about the `item`: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-onclientselectedindexchanged.html

Comment: Ahhh... it's `tr.rtlRL` not `tr.rtlR`

Comment: @JFB Your markup shows both class on the row.  I just chose the first one.

Comment: I edited the markup above. There were a few things I ommited, maybe they were important to show...